# Infinite loop in the background in java

Tags: java, loops, background, infinite

I have written a java program where I need a continuous loop in the background.
But with a normal while loop does not work the program.

In my program a method should be executed either all the time or every second.
In this method, many conditions should be checked and a label should be updated, which indicates a time .
I have already programmed this method, but I do not know how to write a loop that runs in the background so continue buttons can be pressed.

Comment: you can show your code

Comment: The code , however, is very long , so it is not worthwhile to show all the code . Simply said I have to use only the method conditions in a continuous loop at the end of the constructor.

As already explained must be a special loop .

Comment: What UI package do you use? swing? javafx? Normally you run your method in a different thread and post updates to the ui thread.

Comment: I use the Swing Package in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

     public void run() {
          doSomething();
     }

});
thread.start;
```

Everything in the run method will be executed in another thread, so it's not blocking the ui.